# Pandas Rolling second Highest Value based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

For below sample data:

```
data={'Person':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
     'Sales':['50','60','90','30','33','100','600','80','90','400','550'],
     'Price':['10','12','8','10','12','10','13','16','14','12','10']}
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For each person (group) I would like the price based on the **second highest Sales** on a rolling basis but the window will be different for each group. The result should look like:

```
result={'Person':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
     'Sales':['50','60','90','30','33','100','600','80','90','400','550'],
     'Price':['10','12','8','10','12','10','13','16','14','12','10'],
     'Second_Highest_Price':['','10','12','12','12','','10','10','10','12','10']}
```

I tried using nlargest(2) but not sure how to get it to work on a rolling basis.

Comment: You can use `df.groupby("Person").apply(custom_function_to_find_second_highest_sales)`

Comment: What is the window size? Looks like increasing window size with 2nd biggest so far (at each step).

Comment: See if it works for you my solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not the most elegant solution, but I would do the following:

1- Load Dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data={'Person':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
     'Sales':['50','60','90','30','33','100','600','80','90','400','550'],
     'Price':['10','12','8','10','12','10','13','16','14','12','10']}

data=pd.DataFrame(data)

data['Sales'] = data['Sales'].astype(float)
```

2- Use Groupby and expanding together:

```
data['2nd_sales'] = data.groupby('Person')['Sales'].expanding(min_periods=2) \
                                  .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).values[-1]).values
```

3- Calculate the `Second_Highest_Price`:

```
data['Second_Highest_Price'] = np.where((data['Sales'].shift() == data['2nd_sales']), data['Price'].shift(),
                                (np.where((data['Sales'] == data['2nd_sales']), data['Price'], np.nan)))

data['Second_Highest_Price'] = data.groupby('Person')['Second_Highest_Price'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
data['Second_Highest_Price'].values

array([nan, '10', '12', '12', '12', nan, '10', '10', '10', '12', '10'],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: I ran into an issue with indexing in step 2 on actual data since we are assigning the array to the df.  I wasn't able to get it to work as is but I used data_groupby['Sales'].rolling(30,2).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).nlargest(2).iloc[-1] ).values

Comment: Sounds good. My solution should work if your original dataset looks like the example you provided above. If your data is different,you can share a minimal example as well. Here is a notebook reproducing the above example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z3QRTAkDNy7phJ-VKBUIy3OD50K-tNL-?usp=sharing